# How to disable connection pooling and make a new connection for each request in OkHttp3

Tags: java, okhttp

Because of the server side problem, we are trying to disable the connection pool used by OkHttp.
The initializer for OkHttp ConnectionPool class receives maxIdleConnections and keep alive duration information.

```
public ConnectionPool(int maxIdleConnections, long keepAliveDuration, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
  this.delegate = new RealConnectionPool(maxIdleConnections, keepAliveDuration, timeUnit);
}

public RealConnectionPool(int maxIdleConnections, long keepAliveDuration, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
  this.maxIdleConnections = maxIdleConnections;
  this.keepAliveDurationNs = timeUnit.toNanos(keepAliveDuration);

  // Put a floor on the keep alive duration, otherwise cleanup will spin loop.
  if (keepAliveDuration <= 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("keepAliveDuration <= 0: " + keepAliveDuration);
  }
}
```

Would it be ok to set `maxIdleConnections` to 0?
We just need to create a new connection for each request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, Set `maxIdleConnections` to 0.

Comment: Question is "How to disable connection pooling and make a new connection for each request in OkHttp3" - seems to answer.